# Como puedo hacer que el evento mouseenter se detecta cuando esta en los li

Tags: javascript, mouse, li

Tengo una duda como puedo entrar a los li con el evento mouseenter ya e intentado entrar a los li pero solo me detecta el evento con el primer li que se encuentran, los demas li los demas li no se detectan por que no se parece en console.log correspondiente como puedo hacer para que se detecten los demas li y no solo el primero

```
    const primerapregunta = document.createElement(`div`)
    primerapregunta.textContent = `Continúa cada una de las sucesiones según el criterio que te parezca más sencillo`
    primerapregunta.classList.add(`preguntas`)
    
    playjuego.insertAdjacentElement(`afterend`, primerapregunta)
    setTimeout( async () => {
        const respuestapregone = document.createElement(`div`)
        respuestapregone.innerHTML = ` 
        <ol class="respuestas">
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta1"> compasivo </li>
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta2"> reconfortante </li>
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta3"> explicativo </li>
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta4"> entrometido </li>
        </ol>
        `
        primerapregunta.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, respuestapregone) 
        const resp =document.querySelector(`ol`)
        setTimeout(() => { 
            const solucion = resp.querySelector(`li`) 
            solucion.addEventListener(`mouseenter`,()=>{
                switch(solucion.id){
                    case `respuesta1`: 
                        console.log(`Respuesta1`)
                    break; 
                    case `respuesta2`:
                        console.log(`Respuesta2`)
                    break; 
                    case  `respuesta3`:
                        console.log(`Respuesta4`)
                    break; 
                    case `respuesta4`: 
                        console.log(`Respuesta4`)
                    break; 
                    default: 
                    console.log(`No funciono`)
                }
            })
    },2000)
    })
}[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código que compartes, se observa que la forma como intentas darle el evento a los elemento `<li>` es erronea, ya que al hacer lo siguiente:

```
solucion = resp.querySelector(`li`)
```

la variable solución está quedando con un solo elemento, entonces al aplicar el evento solo se lo das a una de las `<li>` y el resto de los elementos existentes quedan sin el evento.

Para esto, he modificado el código un poco empezando desde como obtienes los elementos `<li>` el cual queda de la siguiente manera:

```
solucion = resp.getElementsByTagName(`li`);
```

Así, obtenemos una colección de los elementos que necesitas, por tal motivo creamos un ciclo de repetición, para anexarle el evento a cada elemento obtenido en nuestra lista de tipo `HTMLCollection`.

Comparto el código corregido y funcional.

```js
const playjuego = document.getElementById('playjuego');
const primerapregunta = document.createElement(`div`);
primerapregunta.textContent = `Continúa cada una de las sucesiones según el criterio que te parezca más sencillo`
primerapregunta.classList.add(`preguntas`);

playjuego.insertAdjacentElement(`afterend`, primerapregunta)
setTimeout(async() => {
  const respuestapregone = document.createElement(`div`)
  respuestapregone.innerHTML = ` 
        <ol class="respuestas">
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta1"> compasivo </li>
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta2"> reconfortante </li>
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta3"> explicativo </li>
            <li class="posibleresp" id="respuesta4"> entrometido </li>
        </ol>
        `
  primerapregunta.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, respuestapregone);
  const resp = document.querySelector(`ol`);

  setTimeout(() => {
    // Reemplazamos querySelector por getElementsByTagName
    const solucion = resp.getElementsByTagName(`li`);

    // Creamos el for/of para recorrer el HTMLCollection obtenido
    for (let element of solucion) {
      element.addEventListener(`mouseenter`, () => {
        switch (element.id) {
          case `respuesta1`:
            console.log(`Respuesta1`)
            break;
          case `respuesta2`:
            console.log(`Respuesta2`)
            break;
          case `respuesta3`:
            console.log(`Respuesta3`)
            break;
          case `respuesta4`:
            console.log(`Respuesta4`)
            break;
          default:
            console.log(`No funciono`)
        }
      })
    }
  }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<div id="playjuego"></div>
```

Espero te sirva.